# Can't get CSS Horizontal Scrolling to work

Tags: html, css

I have a project I am working on where we want a number of panels next to each other and display a horizontal scroll bar if all of the panels cannot be shown on the screen at once (typical case). I have spent the day trying to prototype how this might work with some simple HTML and CSS, but I can't get it 100% there. I have tried this in both IE 9 and Chrome 29.x. Both render the same.

Basically, I can't get the non-visible panels **not to wrap** to the next "line". But, (in the case of the markup below), Panel 5 is not visible as it has wrapped down. The HTML below is about as far as I can get with some important differences:

1. Ultimately, I **don't** want to specify a width for #scrollBox (currently set to 1200px). We want to leave this open ended so that this area will always track and grow with the user's browser window.
2. I am not sold on using  or  tags, they are just what I know and work in my overall design.
3. Yes, currently fieldset.firstPanel and fieldset.otherPanel are identical, that may change in the future. same with div.firstPanel and div.otherPanel.

Any help will be appreciated.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Horizontal Scrolling Panels</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        fieldset.firstPanel {
            height: 200px;
            width: 300px;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
        fieldset.otherPanel {
            height: 200px;
            width: 300px;
            margin-right: 10px;
        }
        div.firstPanel {
            height: 200px;
            width: 300px;
            float: left;
            display:inline-block;
        }
        div.otherPanel {
            height: 200px;
            width: 300px;
            float: left;
            display:inline-block;
        }
        #scrollBox {
            width: 1200px;
            height: 220px;
            overflow-x: auto;
            overflow-y: hidden;
            -ms-overflow-x: auto;
            -ms-overflow-y: hidden;
            white-space: nowrap;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="form1" method="post" action="Default.aspx" id="form1">
        <div>
            <div id="scrollBox">
                <div class="firstPanel">
                    <fieldset class="firstPanel">
                        <legend>Panel 1</legend>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div class="otherPanel">
                    <fieldset class="otherPanel">
                        <legend>Panel 2</legend>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div class="otherPanel">
                    <fieldset class="otherPanel">
                        <legend>Panel 3</legend>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div class="otherPanel">
                    <fieldset class="otherPanel">
                        <legend>Panel 4</legend>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div class="otherPanel">
                    <fieldset class="otherPanel">
                        <legend>Panel 5</legend>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic styles for this would be `display:inline-block` on the elements (no floating) and `white-space: nowrap;` on the container:

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5A9c9/2/)**

```
    #scrollBox {
        overflow-x: auto;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        -ms-overflow-x: auto;
        -ms-overflow-y: hidden;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    #scrollBox > div {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    #scrollBox > div fieldset {
        height: 200px;
        width: 300px;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, koala_dev, now I just need to run off and figure out _why_ this works!

Comment: Ah, OK. I see what you are saying now. I was thrown off by the ">" (direct descendant combinator) that I never used before. So basically I was close, I just needed to remove "float: left".